# iOS Share Extension can not work HTTP request and shows many errors

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

Recently when I selected the my share extension at share extension list using real device iPhone5s which OS is iOS8.2, debugger showed many errors and sometimes could not HTTP request and showed HTTP request timed out error.
The simulators do not show these problems.

The errors are these.

```
2015-12-06 22:57:47.566 MyExtension[2253:205758] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/B6C509D1-E530-4EA3-955F-B2B9FE81025B. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:47.567 MyExtension[2253:205758] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/371AF890-421A-48FB-97E6-FB985591CA3E. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:47.592 MyExtension[2253:205761] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/EC88B5E5-64F6-4493-A8F8-457117959EA4. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:47.598 MyExtension[2253:205761] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/4D3FF458-958E-4424-B8D7-68B4C3FECCAC. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:47.600 MyExtension[2253:205757] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/AB4F85FA-4A54-4C9F-B747-F4C1E8341FE1. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:52.225 MyExtension[2253:205760] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/ED8F725F-F2D8-4F21-A552-B1ADAFF9D067. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:52.576 MyExtension[2253:205760] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/52C9C454-B39B-4E70-8320-3D4FF80FB531. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:52.733 MyExtension[2253:205811] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/C8E5B449-044A-4403-8D8F-AD656727F0DB. Errno: 2
2015-12-06 22:57:52.803 MyExtension[2253:205811] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DA4D2743-D409-40F2-82A1-C90B2625008E/Library/Caches/myBuildIdentiferAndAppExtensionName/fsCachedData/10C106BC-272E-4041-AC29-14887EA544C4. Errno: 2
```

Environmental
real device iPhone5S iOS8.2
Xcode 7.1.1
not use Cocoapods
mac mac book pro OS Capitan

Before 1 week, I think these errors did not show and HTTP request was OK.
But, recently these bugs showed. So, I did these.

1. delete Xcode and install Xcode => no effect
2. update mac OS from Yosemite to Capitan => no effect
3. build the project another mac device which is mac book air => no effect

If anyone know the solution or the errors, please tell me.